# How to Store PHP session in aws memcached?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, memcached

I have created memcached in aws and get the end point. I also changed `php.ini` file `session.save_path` and `session.save_handler`.

code in php.ini given below:

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path=configuration end point.
```